# How to create TRIGGER with a reference to the triggered table?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Can I create an AFTER TRIGGER on a table and using that table in my SELECT query without getting mutating table error?

Example to a query I want to use.
This query will update number of times a certain status name is showing up in alert life cycle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER COUNT_STEP
   AFTER INSERT
   ON STEPS
   FOR EACH ROW
   DECLARE
   V_COUNT_SETP   VARCHAR (10000);
BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT (STATUS_NAME)
       INTO V_COUNT_SETP
       FROM (SELECT A.ALERT_ID, S.STATUS_NAME
                FROM ALERTS A, ALERT_STATUSES S, STEPS ST
              WHERE     :NEW.ALERT_INTERNAL_ID = A.ALERT_INTERNAL_ID
                    AND ST.ALERT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ID = S.STATUS_INTERNAL_ID
                    AND S.STATUS_NAME IN ('Auto Escalate'))
   GROUP BY ALERT_ID;

   UPDATE ALERTS A
      SET A.COUNT = V_COUNT_ESC
    WHERE A.ALERT_INTERNAL_ID = :NEW.ALERT_INTERNAL_ID;
END;    
/
```

The table I'm inserting a record to is also needed for counting the number of step occurrences since it's stores the alert id and all the steps id it had.

Comment: Please have a lok at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. To improve you question, try to build a small example, clearly describing what your trigger should do, what you tried and the issues you are having

Comment: It looks like you're missing a join from your alerts table to the steps and/or alert_statuses tables. That seems wrong. Also, does the STEPS.ALERT_INTERNAL_ID column contain unique values?

Comment: @Boneist I thought the join for alert is with the :NEW.ALERT_INTERNAL_ID = A.ALERT_INTERNAL_ID

Comment: That depends; is ALERT_INTERNAL_ID a unique column? If it is, then a) your cross join is going to be mimicking an inner join, and b) why are you even joining that table in the first place? You could remove the STEPS table from the query completely, thus removing the cause of the mutating table issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a bit more clearer in your questions. But, from what i understood, you need to create a trigger on a table, and perform a select for that same table. That gives you a mutanting table error. To bypass that, you need to perform a compound trigger on that table. Something like this:

```
create or replace trigger emp_ct
for insert on employees compound trigger 

  v_count number;  -- Add variable here

  before statement is 
  begin
    -- PERFORM YOUR SELECT AND SEND TO A VARIABLE
  end before statement;


  after each row is 
  begin
    -- DO WANT YOU WANTED TO DO. USE THE VARIABLE 
  end after each row;
end;
```

basically, with a compound trigger, you can capture every trigger event. By doing that, allows to query the table you're capturing.

Comment: not sure how can I use the value I've selected from the before statement in the after statement. I mean if I'm doing a SELECT COUNT(...) how do I update this value in the UPDATE statement that comes after?

Comment: I added the declaration of the variable.

Comment: Thanks! you just made my day! :)